# Using OAuth to access 3dCart api

Tags: api, oauth

Trying to authorize an 'app' in 3dcart

The api is fairly well documented using Swagger and they have this page w/ instructions https://apirest.3dcart.com/v1/getting-started/index.html#getting-started

You are supposed to make this first call, which is supposed to give you token you use in the subsequent step

```
https://apirest.3dcart.com/oauth/authorize?
Client_Id=22613fdfc5a6200bece02a29524XXXXX
&state=12345
&response_type=code
&store_url=www.***********.com
&redirect_uri=www.!!!!!!!!!!.com     <==============  WHAT SHOULD THIS BE
```

Using postman, I can play with the various parameters.

I beleive clientId should be the guid-ish string you get associated w/ each store that has subscribed to your app.

Store Url - i know this. Should I include the https:// protocol in the string?

It sounds like STATE is just something you pass in and the store parrots it back to you.

redirect_uri - not sure what this is/ should be

I can get status 200 OK, but i am getting an HTML page .
Pasting same URL in a browser, I am getting a login page. I login as an admin user and then get 404 because it is redirecting me to the redirect_uri

??? I really just want to login. I tried passing in a blank uri and omitting the parameter. Both yield

```
Status 400 Error 101  redirect_uri is required
Am I doing this correctly? Is there an example of authorizing so you can use the API?
```

I have downloaded the GIT repository. That helps a bit, but still missing something

tyia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the URL you're talking about will allow the customer to grant access to your application. The Redirect URI in the URL you have the customer click on MUST match the Redirect URI you have set up on your app in 3dcart Developer.

After that, there are 5 steps to getting the Authorization Token and then use it to work with the 3dcart API.

The redirect URI is your endpoint where 3dcart will send the code.

Step one:
Set up your Redirect URIs: under the Oauth tab on your application on 3dcart Developers

Step 2:
3dcart will post to this URL a "Code". You can get this from the URL with GET

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

Step 3:
Use Curl (or whatever) to make a postback to 3dcart with the code

```
$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://apirest.3dcart.com/oauth/token");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

            $data = array('Code' => $code, 'client_id' => '{your public app key}', 'client_secret' => '{your private app key}', 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Step 4:
parse the response to get the access_token:

```
$info = json_decode($response, true);
$access_token = $info['access_token'];
```

Step 5:
Use the Access token to make calls to 3dcart using the following parameters in curl

```
$auth = array(
"Content-Type: application/xml",
"Accept: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://apirest.3dcart.com/3dCartWebAPI/v2/{API END POINT}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I was not super clear, when I asked the question , exactly what OAuth was.  I do greatly appreciate this detailed answer.